# Nested File Autocompletion in Emacs?

Tags: auto-complete-mode, directories

I'm using emacs (technically: spacemacs with helm). It seems that any time I call a function which requires a directory, I am presented with something like the following:

[image]

The problem:

If I am in `/a/path/to/a/directory` but I want to get to `/a/path/to/a/directory/that/has/a/deep/nested_file`, I cannot just type `nested_file` and have it autocomplete. Instead I have to type each nested level of directories before I can get to `nested_file`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: https://github.com/bling/fzf.el might be of interest.

Comment: If you've visited the file before and have recentf enabled, helm-recentf will let you open the file quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use package `helm-locate` while searching by issuing `C-u C-x C-f`. This will, however, search globally.

If you are in a Git repository you can also do `helm-ls-git-ls` with `C-x C-d`, searching in the Git repository. This requires the package `helm-ls-git`.

See also https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/539 as a reference.

**Edit**: You need to set keybindings as follows:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'helm-find-files)
```

Comment: `helm-locate` seems to search for directories. In this particular case, (i.e., with `append-to-file`) the command is searching for files, and issuing `C-u C-x C-f` doesn't start helm-locate. I'm running Emacs 25.

Comment: I added a bounty for a related question in case it's of interest: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34087/how-does-emacs-know-to-use-helm-find-files-in-this-context