# How does emacs know to use `helm-find-files` in this context?

Tags: spacemacs, helm

There is a stock emacs function called `append-to-file` that is defined as follows (in `files.el`):

```
(defun append-to-file (start end filename)
  "Append the contents of the region to the end of file FILENAME.
When called from a function, expects three arguments,
START, END and FILENAME.  START and END are buffer positions
saying what text to write."
  (interactive "r\nFAppend to file: ")
  (write-region start end filename t))
```

I'm running spacemacs, which runs helm. When this stock function is called via `M x append-to-file`, an interactive prompt comes up that seems to use `helm-find-files` to help the user find a file to input into this stock function.

**Question:** How does this emacs function -- which was presumably written years before helm ever was -- know to call `helm-find-files` when prompting the user for an input file in the minibuffer?

**Motivation:** The reason why I'm curious about this is that I'm ultimately wanting to call a different interactive file-finding function (one other than `helm-find-files`) with this function (for example I'd like it to invoke `helm-projectile-find-file` which is slightly different).

---

**EDIT:** Using bmag's answer, I have a partial solution that doesn't use `helm-projectile-find-file` but instead uses the shell `find` command to get a list of files I'm interested in.

In particular, I'm interested in the list of files brought up by the shell command `find -L /path/to/files -wholename */capture.md`). How can I put this result into `:sources` below and have the appropriate buffers come up?

```
(defun helm-append-to-file (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((filename
         (helm :sources ... ;; <--what do I put here?
               :buffer "*helm append to file*"
               :prompt "File to append to: ")))
    (append-to-file start end filename)))
```

Comment: I think you could do this with customizing `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`, but I am not completely sure how to set it correctly to your needs, probably something like `(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '((ido-find-file . helm-projectile-find-file)))` or `(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '((append-to-file . helm-projectile-find-file)))` will do.

Comment: @theldoria: That conceptually seems like it should do it, but neither of those options worked for some reason.

Comment: @theldoria: I added a 50 point bounty to this question. If you could help me refine your solution to something that works I would gladly fork over the 50 points :)

Comment: Hello George. What is your current value of the variable `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`? Does it contain `append-to-file`?

Comment: You would have to implement a replacement for `helm-comp-read`, which in turn uses `helm-projectile-find-file` and put that as the value of the `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist` key `append-to-file`: e.g. `(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '((append-to-file . helm-projectile-comp-read)))`. But that's probably overkill - and maybe there exists a cleaner solution.

Comment: The doc-string of `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist` indicates that it is only useful for Emacs commands which call exact `(completing-read ...)`, thus doesn't work for the interactive form such as `(interactive "r\nFAppend to file: ")` used by `append-to-file`.

Comment: BTW, It is much easier to write your own version of `append-to-file`.

Comment: @xuchunyang: Would you know how to write a custom `append-to-file` which calls `helm-projectile-file-file`?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because it is based on incorrect fact: it isn't `helm-find-files` at all thus you should not asking how to use `helm-projectile-find-file` instead. However, if you ask "How to complete against project files in append-to-file?" instead, it is easy to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @db48x wrote, `append-to-file` uses Emacs' default completion facilities, which means calling the function `completion-read`. In turn, the variable `completing-read-function` determines what backend to use for completion. By controlling `completion-read-function` you decide what completion interface you want. Reading file names is a bit different, because it's done by `read-file-name` which is controlled by `read-file-name-function`. However, the default behavior is that `read-file-name` calls `completing-read`.

When `helm-mode` is enabled, it sets `completing-read-function` to `helm--completing-read-default` and `read-file-name-function` to `helm--generic-read-file-name`. In addition, in newer Emacs version (24.4+) Helm uses `add-function` to override these variables instead of `setq`. I assume that's because with `setq` it needs to know the original value when disabling `helm-mode`, but with `add-function` it doesn't.

The completion you get when invoking `append-to-file` is actually a generic helm file name completion, which isn't as heavy and feature-rich as the command `helm-find-files`. In fact, most Helm commands don't use `interactive` to read arguments, because they want more features than the generic Helm completion. Instead, they have a minimal `interactive` declaration and call `helm` function for reading arguments and performing actions, thus utilizing Helm's features. Notably, this includes `helm-find-files` and `helm-projectile-find-file`.

To change the default completion backend, you can just disable `helm-mode` and set `completing-read-function` and `read-file-name-function` to whatever you wish. Helm commands will still function through Helm as usual, and won't be affected by this change.

Alternatively, if you want `append-to-file` to use different completion, but still use Helm as the general completion backend, you will need to wrap `append-to-file` in another command. That command should read the arguments and then call `append-to-file` (non-interactively). With Helm, you could start with the following and modify according to your needs and how much of Helm's features you want to use:

```lisp
(defun helm-append-to-file (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((filename
         (helm :sources some-helm-sources
               :buffer "*helm append to file*"
               :prompt "File to append to: ")))
    (append-to-file start end filename)))
```

Note that if `(helm ...)` changes the current buffer or region then `append-to-file` won't append the region you expect it to, so you'll want to wrap `(helm ...)` in a `save-excursion` or similar. You could use `:candidates` instead of `:sources`, but at that point you won't be much better off than the generic Helm completion. You might be lucky enough to find suitable pre-existing sources, so you don't need to write your own, but otherwise you will have to learn how to write a Helm source. You can look at `helm-projectile.el` and the macro `helm-projectile-command` to see how helm-projectile commands are defined.

For more info on Emacs completion you can visit [section 19.6 of the elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Completion.html#Completion) or read the relevant functions' documentation.

**EDIT: Using find and Helm**

The solution below uses the shell command `find` to get a list of filenames. I use `split-string` so the files show up in the Helm prompt without the common prefix (instead I include the common prefix in the source's name). Because of that, I need to use `f-join` to so `append-to-file` gets the correct filename. Note that Helm has a transformers feature to alter how candidates are displayed, but I didn't use them here since I'm less familiar with them.

Using `f-join` brings a dependency on `f.el`, which you will need to install (in Spacemacs it's already installed). Using `seq-map` brings a dependency on `seq.el`, which requires Emacs 25.1 or newer. Both of these can be replaced by functions available in Emacs 24.5 and older (`cl-map` instead of `seq-map`, several string and filename functions instead of `f-join`).

```lisp
(require 'f)
(require 'helm)
(require 'seq)

(defun helm-append-to-file (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((path "/path/to/files")
        (relative-filename
          (helm :sources (helm-build-sync-source "append"
                          :candidates (get-candidates path))
                :buffer "*helm append to file*"
                :prompt "File to append to: "))
        (filename (f-join path relative-filename)))
    (append-to-file start end filename)))

(defun get-candidates (path)
  "Get names of capture files.
Return a list of filenames. Each filename is relative to PATH."
  ;; use -print0 just in case a filename contains a newline
  (let ((find-command (format "find -L '%s' -wholename '*/capture.md' -print0" path)))
    ;; remove common path prefix so candidates are easier to read in helm prompt
    (seq-map (lambda (s) (string-remove-prefix path s))
            ;; "\0" matches -print0
            (split-string (shell-command-to-string find-command) "\0" t))))
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it's still unclear to me how to use `helm-projectile-find-file` in, i.e., the sample function that you provided (`helm-append-to-file`).

Comment: I attempted a solution based off your `helm-append-to-file` and edited my question. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Your edit doesn't state what you tried. I updated my answer with a working solution. Keep in mind that it isn't the most Helm-idiomatic code, due to the lack of transformers, but for private usage I think it's good enough.

Answer (score 3):

I may not be able to supply the full answer, but here's how you can find out.

`append-to-file` is an interactive function, so its arguments are described in the `(interactive ...)` declaration just before the function body. This is stringly-typed data, which is annoying (and there's not much we can do about it now); the argument types are given by single-letter codes embedded in the string. You can look up some pretty good help information just by running `C-h f interactive <RET>`, but better documentation is in chapter 20.2.2 of the the Elisp manual (`C-h i` to open the list of manuals, or find it online). We can see that the `F` code means to input a filename:

```
‘F’
     A file name.  The file need not exist.  Completion, Default,
     Prompt.
```

This is a bit terse, but if you look at the top of this chapter you'll find that `Completion` signifies that Emacs will first call `completing-read` to prompt the user for the filename:

```
Completion
     Provide completion.  <TAB>, <SPC>, and <RET> perform name
     completion because the argument is read using ‘completing-read’
     (*note Completion::).  ‘?’ displays a list of possible completions.
```

Helm thus needs only to modify how `completing-read` works; it could do this by redefining it, or by adding advice to it, but completion is quite a complicated feature so Helm is likely to be more subtle than that. `completing-read` calls into a number of other functions for various things, there are many variables that control the behavior of these functions, etc; see chapter 19.6 of the Elisp manual.

Have fun :)